# How to cancel an awaiting task?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

I am trying to cancel a task awaiting for network IO using CancellationTokenSource, but I have to wait until TcpClient connects:

```
try
{
    while (true)
    {
        token.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        Thread.Sleep(int.MaxValue); //simulating a TcpListener waiting for request
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Secondly, is it OK to start each client in a separate task?

Comment: The TCP class should have a method that accepts a cancellation of some sort, or a timeout so that you can check the CancellationToken after each timeout in a loop.

Comment: AFAIK only .net 4.5 has such option.

Comment: related: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx

Comment: u should post it as an answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the CancellationToken handle instead of creating a new one, it makes the code more simple

```
var task = Listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
task.Wait(MainToken.Token);
MainToken.Token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
```

Answer (score 3):

When you start the task you can use an overload of the [StartNew](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd988458.aspx) to pass a cancellation token that your task will check for cancellations.

Alternatively you could just use [AcceptAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.acceptasync.aspx) and continue doing other work. AcceptAsync will call the OnCompleted method attached via the SocketAsyncEventArgs param you define.

```
internal class Program
{
    private static EventWaitHandle _signalFromClient;
    private static readonly string NameThatClientKnows = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    private static readonly CancellationTokenSource CancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    private const int PingSendTimeout = 30000;
    private static Socket _connectedClientSocket;
    private static Socket _tcpServer;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        _signalFromClient = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, NameThatClientKnows);

        _tcpServer = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        _tcpServer.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 0));
        _tcpServer.Listen(1);

        var asyncOpInfo = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
        asyncOpInfo.Completed += CompletedConnectRequest;
        _tcpServer.AcceptAsync(asyncOpInfo);

        Console.WriteLine("Console stays open, connecting client will say something.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void CompletedConnectRequest(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Client connected");

        _connectedClientSocket = e.AcceptSocket;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(SendSimpleMessage, CancellationTokenSource.Token);
    }

    private static void SendSimpleMessage()
    {
        while (!CancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested && _connectedClientSocket.Connected)
        {
            try
            {
                _connectedClientSocket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("PING"));
                _signalFromClient.WaitOne(PingSendTimeout);
            }
            catch (SocketException) { Dispose(); }
        }
    }

    private static void Dispose()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource.Cancel();

        _connectedClientSocket.Close();
        _tcpServer.Close();
    }
}
```

Of course setup the SocketAsyncEventArgs with a buffer and other necessary items/behaviour.
In Dispose(), I cancel the task and catch any SocketExceptions that may be thrown by calling Socket.Close on both client and server ø_Ø.